# OperationalError: could not connect to server: Operation timed out - when trying to change database from sqlite to postresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm following [this tutorial to configure my zappa app](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/zappa-or-how-to-go-serverless-with-django/) so I can use AWS lambda functions for my django app. I'm up to "Configure the database" so that's what I'm trying to do. My django app uses postgresql so I'm trying to change my zappa app to postgresql (from the default sqlite). I've successfully created a postgres DB instance on Amazon RDS. The instance setting `Publicly accessible` is set to `Yes`.

I've also successfully installed `psycopg2` and `psycopg2-binary` in my zappa app, as well as changing my DB settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': config('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'), 
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

However when I perform `makemigrations` in my zappa app I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/zappatest/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "****-db.**********.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (14.171.84.91) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Did you check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario4 ?

Comment: If after reading that page you still need help, please share more details about your network within AWS: are you using VPC? What are the security group rules of the RDS instance?

Comment: I believe I am using a VPC as my db instance has this: https://i.imgur.com/MraQRUG.png and I'm using the default security group: `default VPC security group`. I've gone through the link you sent me but I'm not 100% sure what category I fall under. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open port 5432 on the aws firewall or on the box itself:

Here is a test on that port:

```
➜ nmap -Pn -p 5432 14.171.84.91
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-06-18 17:54 EDT
Nmap scan report for static.vnpt.vn (14.171.84.91)
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

Comment: How can I open port 5432 on the aws firewall? By the way I gave the wrong IP it is `18.191.94.44`

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: This is on Mac OSX

Comment: That ip 18.191.94.44 is a Mac OS? I thought you say that you are working on AWS?

Comment: Sorry Mac OS is my local distribution. I'm not sure how to find out the linux distribution on my AWS RDS.

Comment: Type cat/etc/*-release to see what distro you are running.

Comment: I can't run that command as I can't connect to the DB instance on my terminal.